# Clear data after update data in datatables for angular 8

Tags: datatables, angular8

i'm using this plugin https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender for could use datatable in angular,  i have a form for search data, it'll be show in table, the problem is when i do many search,  the table update with the new data but also show data of searches before.

Some idea to clear data before update with the new data.

I'm using this code for my dattables.

```
@ViewChild(DataTableDirective, { static: false })
dtElement: DataTableDirective;
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
dtTrigger: Subject<DataTableDirective> = new Subject();


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Hay que dessuscribirse del evento dtTrigger, para poder recrear la tabla.
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------
  // ReDraw Datatable
  reDraw(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      // Destruimos la tabla
      dtInstance.destroy();
      // dtTrigger la reconstruye
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  }
```

Here, i call the function to update datatable with de new data.

```
this._investigadorGrupoService.find(this.InvestigadorGrupo).subscribe((result: any) => {          
      this.reDraw();
      this.ListInvestigadores = result;
      this.bSearchActive = true;          
      $('#processing').addClass("escondido");
    });
```

this is my HTML

```
<table id="dtDataTable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Acciones</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Facultad</th>
              <th>Nombre Grupo</th>
              <th>Es Lider</th>
              <th>Email</th>              
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let i of ListInvestigadores">
              <td>
                <a class="btn btn-warning text-white" (click)="onEdit(i.investigador)">
                  <span [innerHTML]="Tools.GetIconEdit() | safe: 'html'"></span>
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>{{i.investigador.nombres}} {{i.investigador.apellidos}}</td>
              <td>{{i.grupo.facultad.nombre}}</td>
              <td>{{i.grupo.nombre}}</td>
              <td>{{i.esLiderGrupo ? 'Si': 'No'}}</td>              
              <td>{{i.investigador.email}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

```
 reDraw(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.clear().draw(); // Add this  line to clear all rows..
      dtInstance.destroy();      
      // dtTrigger la reconstruye
      this.dtTrigger.next();      
    });
  }
```